# How to get version of UberCart using PHP code

Tags: drupal, ubercart

How to get version number of UberCart (a Drupal module) using PHP code? Please suggest. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a module's version in Drupal doing something like this.

```
$module_name = 'module_name';
if (module_exists($module_name) {
  $module_list = system_list('module_enabled');
  $module_version = $module_list[$module_name]->info['version'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got your answer.

Comment: Glad i could help. if you found my answer helpful could you please accept the answer ? thank you